# Hats, or no hats?

Tags: discussion

[Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/hats-or-no-hats) appears to be joining the millinering crowd. :)  Does Writers have the same option to opt in? Because I would really love some new hats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the feedback from last year, we figured we didn't need to ask the community for input first.  There is no harm in hats -- you can set an "I hate hats" flag and never be bothered -- and for those who like hats, it was a lot of fun.

So we've already opted in.

Comment: wooo! that makes me very hatpy. :)

Comment: Yay for new hats!

Comment: Gosh, I wish all the people in my life were this easy to please. :-)

Comment: Hand out some hats.

Comment: I think this is not really about people, it is about hats. Ask the people in your life if they'd be pleased with hats!